# Google Analytics Campaign not showing up

Tags: javascript, http, google-analytics

maybe I'm just too stupid for this today, but the link built with the URL Builder Tool simply doesn't work...

The URL is like this: `www.myhost.de/?utm_source=newspaper&utm_medium=wallpaper&utm_campaign=Dezember_2013`

The JavaScript from Analytics on the page is:

```
<!-- google tracking -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-307XXXXX-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'myhost.de']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
</script>
```

And if I use the link, the request that is fired by Analytics looks like this:

```
http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?utmwv=5.4.6&utms=6&utmn=796526978&utmhn=www.myhost.de&utmcs=UTF-8&utmsr=1680x1050&utmvp=1664x508&utmsc=24-bit&utmul=de&utmje=1&utmfl=-&utmdt=MYHOST%20-%20Home&utmhid=1467028902&utmr=-&utmp=%2F%3Futm_source%3Dnewspaper%26utm_medium%3Dwallpaper%26utm_campaign%3DDezember_2013&utmht=1386062173012&utmac=UA-307XXXX-1&utmcc=__utma%3D17482222.575449741.1373561003.1386060468.1386060834.81%3B%2B__utmz%3D17482222.1386060834.81.7.utmcsr%3Dnewspaper%7Cutmccn%3DDezember_2013%7Cutmcmd%3Dwallpaper%3B&utmu=qB~
```

But nothing shows up in Analytics. I just don't get it, there is no redirect or anything on the page.

Do I have to actively do something in Analytics or use _gaq.push to actively push the campaign params?

Please be kind if I'm just not getting it today....

EDIT:
The recommended Google Analytics Debugger Plugin seems to show everything is correct:

```
Account ID               : UA-307XXXXX-1
Page Title               : MYHOST - Home
Host Name                : www.myhost.de
Page                     : /?utm_source=newspaper&utm_medium=wallpaper&utm_campaign=Dezember_2013
Referring URL            : -
Hit ID                   : 11522283
Visitor ID               : 575449741
Session Count            : 82
Session Time - First     : Thu Jul 11 2013 18:43:23 GMT 0200 (CEST)
Session Time - Last      : Tue Dec 03 2013 09:53:54 GMT 0100 (CET)
Session Time - Current   : Tue Dec 03 2013 11:44:22 GMT 0100 (CET)
Campaign Time            : Tue Dec 03 2013 09:53:54 GMT 0100 (CET)
Campaign Session         : 81
Campaign Count           : 7
Campaign Source          : newspaper
Campaign Medium          : wallpaper;
Campaign Name            : Dezember_2013
Language                 : de
Encoding                 : UTF-8
Flash Version            : 11.9 r900
Java Enabled             : true
Screen Resolution        : 1680x1050
Browser Size             : 1664x882
Color Depth              : 24-bit
Ga.js Version            : 5.4.6d
Cachebuster              : 689857480
```

Comment: To check the obvious, where did you look ? The content reports might need a few hours to update. The  source/medium should however show up in the real time reports. Plus if you're on Chrome I suggest you install the google analytics debugger from the Webstore (has a much more readable output). However there seems to be nothing wrong with your code (for a german domain you'd need to anonymize the users IP, though), and certainly you do not need to manually push campaign parameters.

Comment: I did look into Reports->Aquisition->Campaigns and there campaign/source/medium are all empty. I will install the Plugin you suggested and check for anonymous IP, which should actually already be activated :D. I'm just using the url for testing now, it will be used in a banner

Comment: Depending on the traffic to your site it can take anything between 4 hours and 48 hours before all tracked data is incorporated into the reports, so a look into real time would help to decide if the data does not arrive (the only problem I could think of at this point would be wrong filters on your view) or if this is simply the usual delay before the info shows up.

Comment: I think it just was time. Now the params shop up. I thought they would be there immediatly